# Efficient Design of DB with several relations - Django

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to know the most efficient way for structuring and designing a database with several relations. I will explain my problem with a toy example which is scaled up in my current situation

Here are the Models in the Django database

1.) Employee Master (biggest table with several columns and rows)

```
class Emp_Mast():
    emp_mast_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    desgn_mast = models.ForeignKey("hr.Desgn_Mast",  on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    qual_mast = models.ForeignKey("hr.Qualification_Mast", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    office_mast =  models.ManyToManyField("company_setup.Office_Mast",     ref_mast = models.ForeignKey("hr.Reference_Mast", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    refernce_mast = models.ForeignKey("hr.Refernce_Mast", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

[image]
This is how the data is displayed in frontend

2.) All the relational field in the Employee Master have their corresponding models

3.) **Crw_Movement_Transaction**

Now I need to create a table for Transaction Data that that stores each and every movement of the employees. We have several Offshore sites that the employees need to travel to and daily about 50 rows would be added to this Transaction Table called Crw_Movement_Transaction

The Crw_Movement Table will have a few additional columns of calculations of itself and rest of the columns will be static (data would not be changed from here) and will be from the employee_master such as desgn_mast, souring_mast (so not all the fields from emp_mast either)

**One way to do this is just define a Nested Relation for Emp_Mast in the serializer for Crw_Movement and optimize it using select_related and prefetch_related to reduce the queries to the database. However that is still very slow, as any number of queries to Emp_Mast are unnecessary. Would it be better design to just store the fields from Emp_Mast in Crw_Movement and update them when Emp_Mast is updated as well. If yes, what is a good way of doing that. Or  should I stick to using Nested Serializer?**